# Is renting a car in South Africa to drive around the country a safe transport option?

Tags: car-rentals, south-africa

Is renting a car a good idea in South Africa, will it make it easier to get around verses other infrastructure, or do driving standards, road quality, hijacking make it not worth it? Would a particular vehicle type be recommended, to handle the road surfaces or/and to look inconspicuous?

Comment: Please split this into several questions. Also remove the opinion based ones since there will be inevitably closed.

Comment: You've asked at least 3 questions now that are subjective.  It's definitely worth having a read of the [help] and following the guidelines in there to avoid more subjective questions being closed.  If you really, really want to ask a subjective question, the [chat] is a good place for it - plus several of the regulars in there have been to Cape Town and South Africa...

Comment: Yes. Up to you. Mostly, no. No. Yes. Yes.

Comment: What else do i need to do to get this question off hold?